# NSToolBar for switchign views in storyboards - OS X (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, nstoolbar

Have been searching quite a while, maybe someone can direct me to a step by step tutorial on understanding how to use NSToolbar to switch between different view controllers and show them below the toolbar. Possibly resizing the window based on the view height and width.

Not familiar with swift, so any objective-c stuff is much obliged. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`NSTabViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTabViewController_Class/index.html) with its `tabStyle` set to `NSTabViewControllerTabStyleToolbar`. 
You can add an `NSTabViewItem` to the tab view controller for each view controller; with the `image` of the tab view item set to the image you want in the toolbar.

This can be setup programmatically or in an interface builder storyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately thats not what i am looking for. So I found out so far that you can switch controllers via a pre-defined action. One of the key parts is to use: 
- instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:
One can setup identifiers for each view. What i cant figure out is how to make firstView to be replaced by secondView... Been at it for quite a while...

Comment: You don't need to do the swap (or even the instantiation). NSTabViewController does that for you

Comment: I understand that this is the easy way out, unfortunately it's not exactly what i want. I want to have an easy customizable NSToolBar. I have made some progress already but I can't still make the code fully work...

Comment: `- (IBAction)changeView:(id)sender {
    
    NSStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; // get a reference to the storyboard
    NSViewController *sourceViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"sourceViewController"];
    [self insertChildViewController:sourceViewController atIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:sourceViewController.view];
}`